# Fire bullet in the direction of travel

Tags: javascript, impactjs

I have trouble trying to work out how to shoot a bullet in 1 of 8 directions.

The player can only point in compass directions 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, etc.

So what I need is a formula that I can use in spawnEntity to send the bullet in the direction the player is facing at a constant speed.

I've tried this;

```
    sinAngle = Math.cos(90) * 1000;
    cosAngle = Math.sin(90) * 1000;

    bulletX = (this.pos.x);
    bulletY = (this.pos.y);
    return { x: bulletX, y: bulletY, sin: sinAngle, cos: cosAngle };
```

The call is like this then;

```
   trajectory = this.calculateAngle();
   ig.game.spawnEntity(EntityBullet, trajectory.x, trajectory.y, { vel: { x: trajectory.sin, y: -trajectory.cos } });
```

But everything is in radians and I'd like it to be in compass degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is convert degrees to radians, then you simply use: `d * (π/180)` where `d` is degrees.

If you also want to be able to say the compass direction (as in North, South, East, West), create an enum and convert these to degrees and use a degrees-to-radians function.

Comment: That, without the java class, is exactly what I already have and which doesn't work.  I am trying to provide the math functions with compass degrees but they are expecting radians.  i need a function that will calculate the x and y based on degrees compass

Comment: So are you fine with using angles instead of some way to represent N, S, E, W, etc? Because that's pretty trivial. Fixing question...

Comment: I have that now but 0 degrees compass comes out as 0 and 180 compass comes out as 270.  flipped and reversed.  i can program around that but don't really feel like that is a good solution

Comment: Stupid me, i had my cos value named sin and vice versa.  D'OH!

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've done any game programming, but you can use MathHelper.ToDegrees to convert your radians to degrees.

Comment: I actually have degrees but I think cos and sin are expecting radians

Comment: Oh, okay.  That'd be ToRadians instead.  Good luck on your game!

Comment: thanks for your help anyway.  and the game, it's more of an exercise than a real project